# Streaming Audio/Video in WPF with early versions of WMP?

Tags: wpf, xaml, video, stream, wmp

I am developing a Wpf App for a large client base, and have
 just found out that Windows Media Player 10+ is required in order to properly use the
MediaElement XAML class in my Form. I personally don't use WMP,
so I did not have it updated in my system (it was version 9, so 
no video played). I know for a fact many of the clients use 
alternative solutions and also may not be able to stream video
this way in this application.

My question is - what alternative can I use that is *fairly* easy
and flexible, but can work with earlier versions of WMP on XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a way around this problem, as the MediaElement sits on top of the WMP player.

However, in terms of a strategy for overcoming this problem, I would include WMP 10+ as part of my deployment package.  You can set it up as a requirement in your installation of your application and thus will ensure that all your users can view video in the app.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try my MediaUriElemet in http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com

It does not require WMP, but does require .NET 3.5 SP1

-Jer